# Good hashing algorithm with proximity to original text input , less avalanche effect?

Tags: python, mysql, string-matching

We need to store a text field ( say 2000 characters) and its unique hash ( say SHA1 ) in a MySQL table.
To test that text already exists in the MySQL table, we generate SHA1 of the text , and find whether it exists in the unique field `hash` .

Now lets assume there are two texts:

1. "This is the text which will be stored in the database, and its hash will be generated"
2. "This is the text,which will be stored in the database and its hash will be generated."

**Notice the minor differences.**

Lets say 1 has already been added to the database, the check for 2 will not work as their SHA1 hashes will be drastically different.

One obvious solution is to use Leveinstein distance, or difflib to iterate over all already added text fields to fine near matches from the MySQL table.

But that is not performance oriented.
Is there a good hashing algorithm which has a correlation with the text content ? i.e. Two hashes generated for very similar texts will be very similar in themselves.

That way it would be easier to detect possible duplicates before adding them in the MySQL table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt anything you're looking for exists, so I propose a simpler solution:

Come up with a simple algorithm for normalizing your text, e.g.:

- Normalize whitespace
- Remove punctuation

Then, calculate the hash of *that* and store it in a separate column (`normalizedHash`) or store an ID to a table of normalized hashes.  Then you can compare the two different entries by their normalized content.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for locality-sensitive hashing. In addition to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing), run a search on this site to get a few pointers.